# .NET // vs /// Comments convention

Tags: c#, f#, comments

I am just checking out F#, so apologies if this is a silly question, but in the VS2008 F# CTP 1.9.6.2 'Tutorial' project, both // and /// are used for commenting code.

Is there a functional difference between the two slash vs three slash commenting, or is it convention (as it appears in the tutorial code) to comment a function with /// and use // for everything else?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Using three slashes (///) is a C# convention for [XML Documentation Comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/) that is adopted by F# as well.

Answer (score 11):

/// is for documentation comments. VS will use it when generating intellisense information.

Answer (score 7):

It's similar to `/* comment */` vs `/** documented comment */` in Java.

The latter works the same, but is also recognised by documentation software to be developer documentation - not just a note.

Comment: Which only helps if you know what those comment constructions do in Java, which wasn't the question.

Answer (score 4):

/// or ''' for C# and VB.Net are much more than internal comments.  If one turns on **XML documentation file** in the project properties one can, then use Sandcastle and HTML Help to generate four different documentation type (files & web sites).  See https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/wiki and [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/xml-documentation-comments).  Additional, this can be added to your CI process.